# How do I light this hollow tower of Redstone Lamps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want to light this tower, but controllable from a switch. I'd like to be able to expand this up or down in a modular way.

[image]

The example in the image is being powered with a static setup, just faked by alternating torch/redstone centre blocks, for the purpose of giving an example image. It isn't controllable.

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to fit a completely modular redstone wiring setup into the mere 3x3x2 space available for each lamp ring.

Comment: is it just me or do i not get what exactly your asking?

Comment: I edited this to make it clearer and put your image inline. I made one assumption that I'm not sure of though: when you say you want to control it with switches at "either end", I assumed you meant top and bottom. Is that what you meant? Or do you just mean switches on either side of the bottom? (A switch at the top is going to be hard, FYI.)

Comment: Almost. It doesn't matter which end a single on/off switch is at. Thanks for the edits.

Comment: I've just had a look at this for a good 30-45 minutes and I don't think this is possible. You can do every other level fine, but there's just no space to fit in an inverter to make them all light up at the same time. If you did it so it was 4x4 inside or 2 wood, 1 lamp you might have better success if possible.

Comment: Okay 4x4 inside is a lot easier with doing a spiral up the middle. You run into issues with space for a repeater when you reach the 15 block limit for Redstone. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Was wondering if someone had some ingenious solution that would blow my mind though :(

Comment: Gave this a try, didn't think of anything. (In case it helps, note that the interior pattern doesn't have to be 2 high, just a multiple of 2, as long as it provides power where it needs to.) On the other hand, it would be trivial if you wanted to light a ring every 4 blocks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fully modular system inside a 3x3 or 4x4 (with 1 block/1 lamp per level) is impossible because of the lack of space to fit repeaters or redstone torches in a configuration that will still respond correctly to an on/off switch.

The tallest tower that I could make respond correctly to an on/off switch was this 3x3

[image: redstone lamp tower]

Which uses an upside-down half slab in the middle and next to the unlit lamps and is powered by a redstone torch underneath a solid block (instead of a half-slab) in the middle of the bottom level

The smallest size of free standing tower that I could fit a fully modular system in was a 3x3 with 2 blocks and 1 lamp per level, controlled from the bottom

This is the first part of the control system (there's a redstone torch on the inside side of the block with the torch under it)

[image]

This is the second part of the control system (there's a solid block in the middle of the cross)

[image]

If you built the tower against a wall however, it is possible to fit a fully modular system inside an apparent 3x3 like this

[image]

Comment: Wow, dedication. Thanks for your efforts! Is that one lamp not lit in the first example with the half-block?

Comment: Oh, yes it is unlit, good catch.

Comment: Wonder why that is. Looks like it has active redstone next to it.

Comment: Half-slabs (like any transparent block AFAIK) don't transmit a redstone signal through themselves, the lamps are being powered by the blocks underneath the redstone

Answer (score -4):

minimum space would be 5X5 or 6x6 for repeaters and torches 
Can make 7x7 to make spiral staircase up with reapeters

Comment: Please tell us how to make it work with 3x3, or at least explain exactly why it is impossible.