# How can I control a tower of redstone lamps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

So I think this is slightly related to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/104573/how-do-i-light-this-hollow-tower-of-redstone-lamps) but I'm not sure I fully understand the rules controlling lighting redstone lamps.

Say I have a tower like this:
[image: a hollow cross, 2 high, with redstone lamps on the outside]

Right now, I can light it up (as in the picture) by putting a redstone torch in the bottom middle and putting a solid block in the top middle.  **Is there any way to light it up from a redstone signal?  If so, how?  If not, why not?**

(I always seem to get really frustrated with redstone because it is so convoluted with so many corner cases...)

Also as an additional (not sure if possible) restraint, it'd be nice to be able to keep the redstone input within the 3x3 bounding box (coming from below).

Comment: What is a "tower"? This two block high thing?

Comment: @BlaXpirit yes.  Or higher, but I don't know if that's possible either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few ways to carry controllable power up a 1×1 shaft. As far as I know, the layout you describe in your question, with one modification, is the best that can be done for below-ground powering. Adding redstone on top of the solid block allows one more layer. (I have omitted the lamps in front in order to show the mechanism.)

[image]

Note the second torch below which accepts a control signal.

---

Here is one way to transition from a redstone wire to chained torches within a 3×3 base:

[image]

The key design principle is that each torch in the torch-and-block chain can move the signal horizontally one block, so by moving it off to the corner, we have room to direct the redstone wire into the first torch. Many other patterns are possible.

Comment: Thanks!  Basically, I'm thinking of putting a controllable light in a high 3x3 tower, so ideally I'd like to keep the redstone input within the tower.  Does that make sense?

Comment: So, look at this picture, in which I've implemented your layout: http://i.imgur.com/sdWA8mM.jpg .  I've put up glass walls around the 3x3 area.  Picture the signal coming from below, like where the lever is.  This current layout does not work, because if I shut the lever off, the redstone picks up the signal from the torch, flips on and off, and burns out.

Comment: @NickAldwin Please add that information to your question, instead of explaining your requirements in comments!

Comment: @NickAldwin Updated with one possible 3×3 wiring arrangement.

Comment: Nice, this seems to work great.  Also worth noting: this layout actually allows for one more layer on top (since a powered redstone lamp will light the one above) bringing it to 4 high.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This appears to work, but I don't think it's expandable beyond two high:

[image: hollow cross of redstone lamps, 2 high. underneath is a single block in the middle with redstone torches on all four sides. on the next level down, there is a block under one leg of the cross, with a redstone torch attached to it (under the middle of the cross) and a redstone signal leading to it]
[image: hollow cross of redstone lamps, 2 high. underneath is a single block in the middle with redstone torches on all four sides. on the next level down, there is a block under one leg of the cross, with a redstone torch attached to it (under the middle of the cross) and a redstone signal leading to it]

Comment: Also, is there any way to send the signal to the bottom-most snow block without going out of the 3x3 blueprint?  (One of the things I hate most about redstone is trying to get redstone wire pointed the right way)

Comment: You should add that to your question, and mention that you're looking for the signal to come from the bottom (if you are), rather than the top or sides.